# simplest way to find all files in a directory including all but one sub directory?

Tags: file-io, .net-4.0, directory

In .NET,

```
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(searchDirectory);
        FileInfo[] allFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

will get you all the files including all the files within its subdirectories.

What if I want all the files except for one subdirectory.

What is the simplest way and/or most efficient way I can do that?

I'm in .NET 4.0, c#

Comment: You mean all the files and directories except one directory?

Comment: I meant I want allFiles to have all the files in the directory including all the files in all the subdirectories except for one subdirectory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(searchDirectory);
List<FileInfo> allFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
allFiles.AddRange(dirInfo.GetFiles());

foreach (DirectoryInfo di in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    if (di.Name != "DirIDontWant")
    {
        allFiles.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IntelliSense and MSDN helped me figure this out:

```
List<string> lFiles = new List<string>();
lFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(lPath, "*", SearchOptions.AllDirectories));
```

The GetFiles function is defined on MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx). The first parameter is the directory to search; the second parameter is a filter (* is wildcard to get all files), the third parameter is a flag indicating whether to get only files in the indicated directory or all sub-directories.

Comment: I believe the last param should be `SearchOption` (not plural).

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in the MSDN article, recursively with depth first approach : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx

```
    // Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories  
    // that are found, and process the files they contain. 
    public static void ProcessDirectory(string targetDirectory) 
    {
        // Process the list of files found in the directory. 
        string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string fileName in fileEntries)
            ProcessFile(fileName);

        // Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
        string [] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory);
        foreach(string subdirectory in subdirectoryEntries)
            ProcessDirectory(subdirectory);
    }

    // Insert logic for processing found files here. 
    public static void ProcessFile(string path) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);       
    }
```